# parse-server upload size limit , more than 100MB?

Tags: files, upload, javascript, parse-server

I am trying to upload a file to my parse server(using javascript sdk), but I need to make sure i can upload up to 500MB (for example).

Is it possoible to be done in parse-server ?
Can it be edited in some config file?

Thank you

Comment: I'd guess tweaking this would do it: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/ab06055369efee1e456dfdf5c3a86ceba0f4faf1/src/ParseServer.js `maxUploadSize = '20mb',`

Comment: any idea where would that be on the parse-server-example project? i would like to go from there and edit it if possible. [parse-server-example](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example)

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned you use parse-server-example.

So you will open `index.js` and in this code

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
});
```

You will keep all your code same but you will add a last line

```
var api = new ParseServer({
 ..........
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }, //dont forget to add the coma after the last bracket
maxUploadSize: "500mb"  //you will now have 500mb limit :)
});
```

Comment: Is it built in to allow this to be configured with an environment variable?